# Mediawiki 1.34 doesn't find Localsettings.php on Windows -Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, apache2, php, mediawiki

I'm trying to install Mediawiki 1.34 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS  under Windows (10) Subsystem for Linux via tarball - apparently all the modules are working fine:  phpmyadmin, sql database, apache2. http://localhost/mediawiki/Mw-config ran successfully and produced a valid Localsettings.php

I tried to put the mediawiki directory in /var/www/html/ and  alternatively in /var/lib/ with a symbolic link to  /var/www/html/ but http://localhost/mediawiki keeps telling me : LocalSettings.php not found.

I've put LocalSettings.php in all the directories one can imagine without success. Also executed composer. There are lots of other suggestions on several sites but nothing works. 
To me it is clear that http://localhost/mediawiki/index.php is opened:

---

```
define( 'MW_ENTRY_POINT', 'index' );
/*define( 'MW_ENTRY_POINT', '/var/www/html/mediawiki/' );*/

// Bail on old versions of PHP, or if composer has not been run yet to install
// dependencies. Using dirname( __FILE__ ) here because __DIR__ is PHP5.3+.
// phpcs:ignore MediaWiki.Usage.DirUsage.FunctionFound
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/PHPVersionCheck.php';
wfEntryPointCheck( 'html', dirname( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) );

require __DIR__ . '/includes/WebStart.php';

$mediaWiki = new MediaWiki();
$mediaWiki->run();
________________________________________
```

The values I could retrieve from index.php were as follows

echo (  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );              /Mediawiki/index.php
echo ( dirname( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) );    /Mediawiki
echo ( **DIR** );                               /var/lib/Mediawiki
echo ( **FILE** );                              /var/lib/Mediawiki/index.php
echo (dirname( **FILE** ) . '/includes/PHPVersionCheck.php');           /var/lib/Mediawiki/includes/PHPVersionCheck.php
    ________________________________________
then goes to WebStart.php
    ________________________________________

```
// If no LocalSettings file exists, try to disnano WebStart.phpnano WebStart.phpplay an error page
// (use a callback because it depends on TemplateParser)
if ( !defined( 'MW_CONFIG_CALLBACK' ) ) {
        if ( !defined( 'MW_CONFIG_FILE' ) ) {
                define( 'MW_CONFIG_FILE', "$IP/LocalSettings.php" );
        }
        if ( !is_readable( MW_CONFIG_FILE ) ) {

                function wfWebStartNoLocalSettings() {
                        # LocalSettings.php is the per-site customization file. If it does not exist
                        # the wiki installer needs to be launched or the generated file uploaded to
                        # the root wiki directory. Give a hint, if it is not readable by the server.
                        global $IP;
                        require_once "$IP/includes/NoLocalSettings.php";
                        die();
                }

                define( 'MW_CONFIG_CALLBACK', 'wfWebStartNoLocalSettings' );
        }
```

---

Any idea?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
It was a problem of uppercase /lowercase.
WebStart.php looks for LocalSettings.php whereas the installation script delivered Localsettings.php